# Rails - has_one association with two parameters

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a table called assets which has many versions. The versions have version numbers. Each asset also has a version_number column which indicated the most recent (newest) version.

I would like to set up an association between an asset and its latest version, but I can't find any documentation on how to do that. It would, in theory, look something like this

asset.rb

```
has_one :latest, class_name: "Version", foreign_key: ["asset_id", "version_number"], primary_key: ["id", "version_number"]
```

A naive approach would be:

asset.rb

```
def latest
  Version.where(asset_id: asset.id, version_number: asset.version_number).first
end
```

The problem with doing it just like that in code though, is that I can't load the 'latest' in the association_cache of an asset. I also can't easily eager-load all the assocationed 'latest' records when I load a set of assets, like `Asset.includes(:latest).where(project_id: 7)`.

The reason I think that this *should* be possible is because polymorphic associations use two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered the solution after typing out my question, which helped me phrase the question better. The solution comes courtesy of http://pivotallabs.com/rails-associations-with-multiple-foreign-keys/

TLDR;

```
has_one :latest, class_name: 'Version', foreign_key: :asset_id, primary_key: :id, conditions: Proc.new{|join_association|
  if join_association
    "versions.version_number = assets.version_number"
  else
    {version_number: version_number}
  end
}
```

I had to tweak the line `"versions.version_number = version_number"` a bit, because in some eager-loading situations, SQL would complain about ambiguity for the key version_number. So, I added `assets.` to remove that ambiguity and fix the issue. I would again echo what they say, which is that you must `joins(:latest)` whenever you `includes(:latest)`!